# How to distribute the snow in this snow animation across a wider area?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I found this code on CodePen, but don't understand how it works.

You will notice that the snowflakes are all clustered on the top left corner and the animation isn't playing. How do I fix that?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px white);
}

@function random_range($min, $max) {
  $rand: random();
  $random_range: $min + floor($rand * (($max - $min) + 1));
  @return $random_range;
}

.snow {
  $total: 200;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;

  @for $i from 1 through $total {
    $random-x: random(1000000) * 0.0001vw;
    $random-offset: random_range(-100000, 100000) * 0.0001vw;
    $random-x-end: $random-x + $random-offset;
    $random-x-end-yoyo: $random-x + ($random-offset / 2);
    $random-yoyo-time: random_range(30000, 80000) / 100000;
    $random-yoyo-y: $random-yoyo-time * 100vh;
    $random-scale: random(10000) * 0.0001;
    $fall-duration: random_range(10, 30) * 1s;
    $fall-delay: random(30) * -1s;

    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      opacity: random(10000) * 0.0001;
      transform: translate($random-x, -10px) scale($random-scale);
      animation: fall-#{$i} $fall-duration $fall-delay linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes fall-#{$i} {
      #{percentage($random-yoyo-time)} {
        transform: translate($random-x-end, $random-yoyo-y) scale($random-scale);
      }

      to {
        transform: translate($random-x-end-yoyo, 100vh) scale($random-scale);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="glyka.scss" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the above is a SASS code not a CSS code

Answer (score 1):

This is SCSS and you can't do this in CSS

https://codepen.io/en0ndev/pen/yLavqpK

Use this SCSS:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px white);
}

@function random_range($min, $max) {
  $rand: random();
  $random_range: $min + floor($rand * (($max - $min) + 1));
  @return $random_range;
}

.snow {
  $total: 204;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;

  @for $i from 1 through $total {
    $random-x: random(1000000) * 0.0001vw;
    $random-offset: random_range(-100000, 100000) * 0.0001vw;
    $random-x-end: $random-x + $random-offset;
    $random-x-end-yoyo: $random-x + ($random-offset / 2);
    $random-yoyo-time: random_range(30000, 80000) / 100000;
    $random-yoyo-y: $random-yoyo-time * 100vh;
    $random-scale: random(10000) * 0.0001;
    $fall-duration: random_range(10, 30) * 1s;
    $fall-delay: random(30) * -1s;

    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      opacity: random(10000) * 0.0001;
      transform: translate($random-x, -10px) scale($random-scale);
      animation: fall-#{$i} $fall-duration $fall-delay linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes fall-#{$i} {
      #{percentage($random-yoyo-time)} {
        transform: translate($random-x-end, $random-yoyo-y) scale($random-scale);
      }

      to {
        transform: translate($random-x-end-yoyo, 100vh) scale($random-scale);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "You can't do this in CSS" Sass has to be compiled to CSS before it can be understood by a browser, so anything Sass can do, CSS can do.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to say that it should actually use different file format.

Comment: i have edited the file format. Animation is still now working